# Using DTS Variable for file path using XDocument.Load

Tags: xml, variables, ssis, script-task

I am trying to load an XML file in an SSIS Script task.
This works:

```
var fullpath = "E:/perforce_ws/EnterpriseTrunk/SSIS/Inbox/RCT_Import_1.xml";  
var xml = XDocument.Load(fullpath);
```

But this doesn't:

```
var fullpath = Dts.Variables["XMLFullPath"].Value.ToString;  
var xml = XDocument.Load(fullpath);
```

The error being returned is

> "Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed variable".

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I think you should remove `.ToString` from `Dts.Variables["XMLFullPath"].Value.ToString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToString` is a method group.

`ToString()` is a method call.

The assignment code you were looking for is

```
var fullpath = Dts.Variables["XMLFullPath"].Value.ToString();
```